# How to remove black background color from uitableviewcell from the portion where image should not be displayed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

Hello i have one iphone application in which an `UITableViewCell` is added with a background image using the following code

```
tbView.backgoundColor=[UIColor colorWithImagePattern:[UIImage imagenamed:@"cellbg.png"]];
```

Image is added,  but image should be displayed for some portion only.The portion in which image is not displayed is shown in black color. I want to make that color white.[image]

In picture above show the black that I want to remove where date, friday september is displayed. How can i do that. I have tried to add `UIImage` as a subview to the cell.But the image is larger than the cell size.so it is scaled to cells size and becomes smaller and ins't displayed properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got solved by adding imageview as backgroundview of table

UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellbac.png"]];
background.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTopLeft;
tbView.backgroundView= background;

Answer (score 0):

Try this below line of code:

```
tbView.backgoundColor=[UIColor clearColor]; 
or 
tbView.backgoundColor=[UIColor whiteColor]; 

tbView.backgroundView.opaque = NO;
```

Put above line before you set your background image.

Comment: set your tableview transperant

Comment: tbView.backgoundColor=[UIColor clearColor] means that  tableview is tranperant